# Multiple background image in Subsampling Scale Image View

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, subsampling

I have a demo app in which I have used SubsamplingScaleImageView from Dave Morrissey.
Basically I have a large image which serves as a map, and I need the zoom and pan functionality.

i need set More Image in background (layers),i use PinView but problem is not scaler by zoom in/out. I have the following code:

```
PinView imageView = (PinView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewMap);
imageView.setImage(ImageSource.resource(R.drawable.map));
```

How can I solve this?, and thnx u.

Answer (score 0):

You can use layer-list drawable

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
          <bitmap android:src="@drawable/android_red"
            android:gravity="center" />
        </item>
        <item android:top="10dp" android:left="10dp">
          <bitmap android:src="@drawable/android_green"
            android:gravity="center" />
        </item>
        <item android:top="20dp" android:left="20dp">
          <bitmap android:src="@drawable/android_blue"
            android:gravity="center" />
        </item>
```

[image]

Comment: PinView is not ViewGroup not accpte that